# Custom pagination component

Tags: javascript, jsf

I am looking custom pagination in jsf. I need this custom component as for dropdown.

[image]

I have arraylist to display the dropdown values. The previous and next functions also needed.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but please improve your english and try to explain everything a little better...

Comment: I've fixed the image for you, but you still need to be more precise on what technologies or libraries you can use for this.

Comment: I am using jsf.How to getting the values to here..

Comment: You **need to give us more information** . What are you talking about when you say "values"? What sort of server side code do you have set up? What else do you have other than jsf?