# dropdown with next and previous functions

Tags: javascript, jsf

How to create custom component in dorpdown ? requirment is dropdown with next and previous functionalities.

dropdown have list, we choose the list as well using next and previous button choose list from drop down.

this is jsf dropdown , how to implement the next and previous functions in the dorpdown.

```
(previous)<   (dropdown)    >(next)
```

Comment: Are you, by any chance, the person who asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645882/custom-pagination-component?

Comment: yes , that dropdown is jsf/icefaces component.